# How to specify a property with - in the name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I am using ASP.NET MVC along with JQueryMobile in a web app.  I want to generate a link:

```
<a href="/Whatever/Previous" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l">Previous</a>
```

I have a helper extension method that lets me do:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink<WhateverController>(c => c.Previous(), 
         "Previous", 
         new { data-role = "button", data-icon="arrow-l" } ) %>
```

Except `data-role` and `data-icon` are not valid as property names in C#.  Using `@data-role` doesn't work either.

Is there any syntax to work around this?  Or am I stuck with creating a more specialized helper that knows the correct attribute names.

Comment: I have never heard of these attributes. Are you sure they are in the Html specification? does your html validate? By the way you have forgotten an '}' at the end. That may be causing problems too?

Comment: @Jan: They are in the HTML5 specification.

Comment: @Dominic: +1, I learnt something new. Great addition to the Html 5 specification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to use `IDictionary<string, object>` instead of the anonymous object:

```
Html.ActionLink<WhateverController>(c => c.Previous(), 
     "Previous", 
     new Dictionary<string, object>
     {
          { "data-role", "button" },
          { "data-icon", "arrow-l"}
     })
```

Comment: Unfortunately after trying it this doesn't actually seem to work.  I get:  <a comparer="System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer`1[System.String]" count="1" keys="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[System.String,System.Object]" values="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection[System.String,System.Object]" ...>

Comment: Hmm, actually, it seems MVC 2 doesn't have the method `ActionLink` in this generic form, so I think you (or a library you use) have an extension method to do this, but you have only the one that takes `object` and not the one that takes `IDictionary`.

Comment: That's the problem with extension methods ... you never know where they are coming from.  Looks like it is coming from Microsoft.Web.Mvc which was maybe part of the MvcFutures project sometime ago?  Adding this as an extension method makes sense.

Comment: Uh, you never know where classes are coming from either unless you highlight and wait for the namespace to pop up.  Lambda based ActionLinks were removed because they perform slowly.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to svick's response, we made a neat change in ASP.NET MVC 3 where properties that have an underscore in them will automatically have the underscores converted to dashes.

So, if you have code like this:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink<WhateverController>(c => c.Previous(),  
     "Previous",  
     new { data_role = "button", data_icon="arrow-l") %>
```

It will render the markup with dashes:

```
<a href="/Whatever/Previous" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l">Previous</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a neat addition. Unfortunately I also need this to run on mono, so I'll have to hold off for a little bit on adopting it.

Answer (score 1):

Because that character is also the subtraction/unary minus operator you can't use it in an identifier.  I think the custom helper method is probably your best bet.

Comment: Thanks -- that's actually what I did since I have a reasonable number of these and whilst svick's answer is the most technically correct for the stated problem, avoiding the problem is a more pragmatic solution!